# wants to devide a string in three part

Tags: python, spliterator

string = "M/s Indian Tobacco Co. pvt. ltd., Godfrey Philips,  VST Industries",

'''if starting word is M/s then it will devide it three part as end" ," character '''

```
like so
'''
[."M/s Indian Tobacco Co. pvt. ltd",
 "Godfrey Philips",
 "VST Industries"]'''
```

Comment: you have forgotten to post your code and explain whats not working with your code or the error you get

Comment: You should pay more atention on how to make a good question. You cannot copypaste some stuff here hoping someone will underestand.

Comment: What should happen if the string doesn't start with "M/s"?  Do you really want a string as result?  And if so what format (it's inconsistent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def process(string):
    if string.startswith("M/s"):
      return '\n'.join(f'{i}. {p.strip()}' for i, p in enumerate(string.split(','), start=1))
    else:
      # question does not specify what should happen
      return string

print(process("M/s Indian Tobacco Co. pvt. ltd., Godfrey Philips, VST Industries"));
```

Gives the output:

```
1. M/s Indian Tobacco Co. pvt. ltd.
2. Godfrey Philips
3. VST Industries
```

Comment: if string start with M/s then it will find their "," and will devide then as   Ex . "M/s The Tata Power Com. Ltd., Jojobera Power Plant" this start with M/s then it would be devide in two parts   1. M/s The Tata Power Com. Ltd., 2.Jojobera Power Plant

Comment: yes wants in python

Comment: Anyways, please edit your question.  What should happen if the string doesn't start with that?  One good way is to give us input and matching output, or if that gave you enough information to help you solve the problem mark answer as solved.

Comment: @AllanWind I'd recommend making result a list, appending each part and then doing `'\n'.join(result)`.

Comment: @aneroid good idea (to avoid the last strip()), but you still need to iterate through it to generate the index so might as well just build the string as you go along.

Comment: @AllanWind String building/concatenation in Python is generally bad practice, due to the performance. But this is a small code snippet; with no OP effort. I would have done `'\n'.join(f'{i}. {p.strip()}' for i, p in enumerate(string.split(','), start=1))`.

Comment: @aneroid updated as suggested.  TIL that you can use a list compression outside of a [].

Comment: @AllanWind That's right, you _can't_. I made it a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) - and if the only parameter to a function is a generator expression, then the extra parentheses can be skipped. So for example, the list comprehension inside this - `tuple([i for i in range(3)])` would become the gen-expr `tuple((i for i in range(3)))` and since the outer two parens are for the same one expression, skip one pair and it become `tuple(i for i in range(3))`. (Obviously, the correction version of this is just `tuple(range(3))`.)